# Converting a String with negative numbers and decimals into an int?

Tags: java, string, parsing, int

I'm trying parse a string into an int using `Integer.parseInt(String a)`

However I'm running into a problem where I get the following error:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "-106.55"

Where `-106.55` is one of the Strings I'm trying to convert to an int.

What's going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`"-106.55"` is not an `int`, it's a `double`. Use `Double` to parse it:

```
double d = Double.parseDouble(String a);
```

If you want to keep an `int` portion of it, use a cast:

```
int n = (int)d;
```